# Windows Phone 8.1 DP cellular data

Tags: 8.1, nokia-lumia-920, cellular-data, cellular

I'm using the Nokia Lumia 920 with Windows Phone 8.1 Developer Preview. I face some problem today is I've already turn on the cellular data, it does shows me that it is already turn on, but my top status bar there didn't show that I did turn on the cellular data even I restart my phone and try again also the same problem occur. Besides that, I've tried to surf the internet through the Internet Explorer, I can't even access to the internet through the cellular data even I'm turn it on already. What had happened actually? Hope anyone can help me from this. Thanks in advance.

This screen shot that I've taken with my Nokia Lumia 920. I'm proving that I already turn on the cellular data but status bar there didn't show it up like E, G, H, H+, LTE signal.

[image]

Comment: Try restarting the phone. Or you can try my personal favorite "Turn On flight mode and then turn it Off" :)

Comment: What does it show below the network signal strength, if you swipe the action centre down?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up an access point manually from settings section. Before that turn off cellular data.

You will be required to go to, settings >> access point. Tap "add" application bar button. Give your access point name (you will get it from your operator, in my case its "blweb" as my operator is Banglalink3G). fields like username, password, proxy address, proxy port are not mandatory, you can leave them blank. Use network type "IPv4", and authentication type "PAP". Now turn on your cellular data.

Hope it helps.